# Reverse an array in Assembly x86

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, reverse

I decided to learn Assembly(using emu8086) and I want to learn how to to reverse an array.
So,I want to tranfer this code from C to assembly:

```
   void reverse(int len, char *str)
    {
      int i;
      char temp;

      for (i=len-1; i >= len/2; i--)
       {
         temp = str[i];
         str[i] = str[len-1-i];
          str[len-1-i] = temp;
       }
   }
```

This is the array

```
   chrs db  'A','N','E','X','A','M','P','L','E','$'
```

This is the main

```
    mov ax, offset chrs
    push ax
    push 9
    call reverse
```

So far I can deal with it by myself until I got to the loop part.
I learned how to write a simple loop and also I used this - [While, Do While, For loops in Assembly Language (emu8086)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665528/while-do-while-for-loops-in-assembly-language-emu8086)

So,My main problem is doing the reverse function. Can you please show me how I use it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you how it's possible to write it in C in different way. If you can understand what I did, you should be able to do your asm loop later once you get a bit better accustomed to the computer memory design and how CPU works with it.

```
void reverse(int len, char *str) {
    char *bptr = str;
    char *eptr = str+len-1;
    char temp;

    while (bptr < eptr) {
        temp = *bptr;
        *bptr = *eptr;
        *eptr = temp;
        ++bptr;
        --eptr;
    }
}
```

The loop body of this C can be converted into ASM by using exactly one x86 instruction for each line, and the initial `while` can be done by using two instructions ahead of loop body and one instruction after it.

You should be able to write all this with only `mov`, `inc`, `dec`, `cmp`, `jae`, `ret` and `lea` or `add`.

---

BTW, if you want to learn ASM, don't memorize "how to write loop" by instructions, like some kind of source listing, that's completely useless. You need to memorize (1) what exactly each instruction does, and understand how the loop is achieved through that.

The CPU is deterministic state machine, and each instruction does change that state in simple deterministic manner. So at the start you have CPU in some state, and memory in some state (containing probably some input data, and also your instructions = code), and you know what state you want to achieve at the end (both state of CPU and memory content). And you simply use instructions to change that initial state into the ending state.

If for example your initial state is that `ax` contains value 5, and you want end with `ax` containing value `6`, you have several ways how to achieve that, shorter ones (each has only single instruction) being:

- `mov ax,6`
- `mov al,6`
- `inc ax`
- `inc al`

Ridiculous way wasting many instructions can be:

```
xor ax,ax
dec ah
shr ax,14
add ax,ax
```

That's why memorizing "listings" is useless, there are many many ways how to achieve the state you want.

(1) not exactly, I'm still checking the Intel instruction reference guide almost every time I write some ASM, even after 20+ years of knowing x86 asm. Because often the details matter and I have to be sure the instruction will do exactly what I expect it to do.