# While loops in Assembler

Tags: assembly, mips

I am starting to learn Assembler. Could anyone please help: how may this code look like in Assebler:

```
while (j<16)
do {
    a=A[j];
    b=a+B[a];
}
```

I am a bit confused how `j<16` should be written in the conditional statement for while loop.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C-like syntax, the `do` should be removed.  `do{}while()` loops have the condition at the bottom of the loop (like normal for asm: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While, Do While, For loops in Assembly Language (emu8086)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28665528/5221149)

Comment: This loop is weird because `j` isn't modified anywhere inside the loop so it either runs zero times or infinite.  You just need an `if` to skip over a loop that uses `j` at the bottom.  Of course it has no side-effects other than reading memory, and it's always the same elements read every iteration.  If faulting is a visible side-effect that you need to preserve in asm, then you would at least need address-calculation and loads inside a loop that uses `j` to loop forever.

Comment: @Andreas: nope, MIPS branching is very different from x86; MIPS doesn't have a FLAGS register so you have to compare into an integer register with `slt $t0, $t1, 16` or something, and then branch on that with an instruction like `bne $t0, $zero, target`